# Typescript: How to ban await with Tslint?

Tags: typescript, async-await, tslint

Is it possible to ban usage of Typescript `await` with Tslint? If not, are there other linters out there that can do this?

Comment: Not a fan of `aync`/`await` I take it ..

Comment: Write a custom rule:  https://palantir.github.io/tslint/develop/custom-rules/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using a custom rule. It works for what I need at least.

Create a file (e.g. `noAwaitRule.ts`), and compile with `tsc`.

```
import * as ts from "typescript";
import * as Lint from "tslint";

export class Rule extends Lint.Rules.AbstractRule {
    public static FAILURE_STRING = "await statement forbidden";

    public apply(sourceFile: ts.SourceFile): Lint.RuleFailure[] {
        return this.applyWithFunction(sourceFile, walk);
    }
}

function walk(ctx: Lint.WalkContext<void>) {
    return ts.forEachChild(ctx.sourceFile, function cb(node): void {
        if (node.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.AwaitExpression) {
            const { expression } = node as ts.AwaitExpression;
            const keywordStart = expression.pos - "await".length;
            ctx.addFailure(
                keywordStart,
                expression.pos,
                Rule.FAILURE_STRING,
                Lint.Replacement.deleteFromTo(keywordStart, expression.getStart(ctx.sourceFile)),
            );
        }
        return ts.forEachChild(node, cb);
    });
}
```

If your file is in a sub-directory (e.g. `tslint-rules`), add it to `tslint.json` rulesDirectory`:

```
"rulesDirectory": [
    ...,
    "tslint-rules"
  ],
```

Also in `tslint.json`, add the new rule, which by naming convention becomes `no-await`:

```
"rules": {
    ...,
    "no-await": true
}
```

*Thanks to user Amy for pointing me in this direction.*